# Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$, prove that $y-ra\in I$ for all $r\in R$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$.  If for some $a,b\in R$,

1. $ab=0_R=ba$ and
2. $yb\in I$  for some $0\neq y\in R$.

By stating suitable conditions on $R$ or $I$, prove that $y-ra\in I$ for all $r\in R$.

This is my attempt on the proof:

Since $ba=0=ab$, then $(y-ra)b=yb-(ra)b=yb-r(ab)=yb-r0=yb\in I$.  So that $y-ra\in (I:_Rb)=\{s\in R:sb\in I\}$.  But this does not help me much.

Comment: Sorry, $y$ is a nonzero element in $R$.  We need to show that $y-ra\in I$ for all $r\in R$.  I have made some editing.  Sorry for the typos

Comment: The use of $b$ in both points is a little ambiguous. Are you saying that $a,b$ are fixed elements in 1), and that the $b$ from 1) is the same $b$ in 2)?  If so, it might be better to mention $b\in I$ in 1) instead.

Comment: Yes, the $b$ in (1) is the same $b$ in (2).  The fact that $yb\in I$ for some $y\in R$ gives me an idea that $Rb\subseteq I$, implying that $b\in R$. Now suppose that $b\in I$.  How can the proof be?

Comment: @mariam In 2), how can one suddenly say $b\notin I$ if it was just some element  that is a zero divisor in 1)?  Should we think of the $b\notin I$ as being in 1)?

Comment: I think we can drop the condition $b\notin I$.

Comment: When $r=0$, you have that $y\in I$. Then $ra\in I$ for all $r$. In particular $r=1$ gives you that $a\in I$.  After $a\in I$, $y-ra\in I$. So apparently it is sufficient and necessary that $a,y\in I$, and none of the other stuff matters. Are you sure this question is transcribed accurately? It doesn't feel right to me, or I am missing something...

Comment: @mariam If you drop the condition that $b \not\in I$, then $yb \in I$ tells us nothing about $y$. In fact one special case would be $b = 0$, so that tells us nothing about $a$ either. Then $y \ne 0$ and $a$ could be any elements whatsoever, so $y - ra \in I$ need not hold at all, unless you first assume $y, a \in I$. In the latter case the rest of the information is irrelevant, as rschwieb pointed out

Comment: Can you tell us where you got this problem from?